401 error returned when running backend in docker but not in visual studio
I am facing an strange issue. The backend is written in .Net Core and I add authorization policy to restrict user to visit. Since a user might have multiple roles, I design the policy
as follows in startup.cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IsManager", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        context.User.HasClaim(c =>
            (c.Type == "Role" && c.Value.Contains("Manager"))
    )));
    
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();
});


In the ManagerController I add [Authorize(Policy = "IsManager")] to allow only manager to visit. Now I launch the backend diretly in visual studio, everything works fine. But when I run it in the docker I got 401 error. I check the request and the token is sent to backend. After decoding the token, the payload contains right value
{
  "sub": "18",
  "unique_name": "zl@copmpany.com",
  "Role": "[{\"bit\":1,\"name\":\"M1020 Checker\"},{\"bit\":2,\"name\":\"Checker\"},{\"bit\":4,\"name\":\"Designer\"},{\"bit\":8,\"name\":\"Manager\"}]",
  "nbf": 1720692613,
  "exp": 1720694413
}

Somehow I keep getting 401 error and I have no idea why the policy blocks the visit via docker. There is not cert set in this project.
Can someone help?

Try to enable asp.net core logging feature, and share the logs.
